# What is the different between textExtraction and addParser on jQuery Tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I don't understand what is the different, I am trying to figure out which one is in the end who know what is the text or whatever for sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When tablesorter is initialized, it uses the `textExtraction` function to extract the content from the table. For example, if your table cell has this markup:

```
<tr>
    <td><span class="value hidden">42</span> Forty-Two</td>
    <td>Fred</td>
</tr>
```

The `textExtraction` function can be set to target specific text within a table cell.

```
textExtraction: function(){
    1: function(node, table, cellIndex) {
        return $(node).find('.value').text();
    }
}
```

A parser on the other hand takes the text from the `textExtraction` function and manipulates it so it is easier to sort. For example, if we had this table markup:

```
<tr>
    <td>Fred</td>
    <td>1/31/2014</td>
</tr>
```

A date parser (the shortDate parser in this case) will take that date "1/31/2014" and convert it into a number of milliseconds:

```
new Date("1/31/2014").getTime() // result: 1391148000000
```

this number is much easier to sort and compare.

Of course, there is some overlap between the two, because we can make the `textExtraction` function do this conversion as well; but internally, any value that is returned from the `textExtraction` function is trimmed (using jQuery `$.trim()`) and the result is always returned as a string. So the result would not be the exactly the same as it would be from a parser.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: What about addParser? Why I have to use addParser sometime?

Comment: The `addParser` function is used to [add custom parsers](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers.html) to tablesorter (click the link for more details).

Comment: I read but textExtraction I got it, it's for search inside the element the real text and addParser there I saw like the same almost. Who use the other one.

Comment: Did you look at the add custom parser demo? That parser allows the sorting of table cells that have "good", "medium" and "bad". Also, check out the [grouping widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-grouping.html) which uses the select, input and checkbox parsers.

Comment: Nice answer. @yordis-prieto-lazo don't forget to give Mottie a vote

Comment: @myborobudur I agree nice answer but I am asking for the different between them, where is the explanation of addParser. I need understand the different no what they do and I am asking here because I can't understand the official documentation

Comment: I made remarks about parsers: "A parser on the other hand takes the text from the `textExtraction` function..."; I didn't specifically say "addParser", but that is how a parser is used.